# Given a random variable X, how would I find the probability that it is less than a certain value? No info is given about the distribution of X

Tags: random-variables, density-function

I'm given that $X$ is a random variable with density

$$f(x) = c * e^{−0.5*|x + 5|}$$ for x ∈ R.

How do I find a $t$ such that $P (X ≤ t) = 0.5$? I have no information on the distribution of X. The mod sign makes it even more confusing - do I have to take two cases of it being positive and negative?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you, I've edited it appropriately now.

Comment: According to definition, to find $t$ such that $P(X \leqslant t) = 0.5$, you should find $t$ such that $$ \int_{-\infty}^{t} f(x) dx = 0.5.$$ And yes, you will have to split the integral into positive and negative part because of the absolute value. Someone correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: @Rodrigo Thanks for the explanation, but how exactly would I split the integral limits? Or does -inf to t stay the same, and I've to take two cases of $(x+5)$and $-(x+5)$ and add them up separately? How would I do it?

Comment: Assuming you have no information on $t$: you know that $x+5>0$ iff $x>-5$ and $x+5<0$ iff $x<-5.$ Thus, you have to consider the cases where $t>-5$ and $t<-5.$  When $t>-5$ your integral becomes: $$\int_{-\infty}^{-5} ce^{0.5(x+5)}dx + \int_{-5}^t ce^{-0.5(x+5)}dx;$$ and if $t<-5$ your integral becomes: $$\int_{-\infty}^t ce^{0.5(x+5)}dx. $$

Comment: You also need to be aware that you have an extra constant ($c$). You can determine this constant using properties of the density function of $f$. This will make your calculations easier.

Comment: @Rodrigo Yes, we know c from the density function. Thank you!